# Matplotlib scatter plot with ticks at second intervals and tight xlim

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

This has been driving me crazy. I simply want a scatter plot where the x axis are times and with tick marks every n seconds (say 3). I can get the axis to render dates but for some reason the x-limits are way way to wide for the data I actually collect (from a sensor).

```
 f = arr["f"].values                            
 p = arr["p"].values                            
 ts = arr["time"].values                                     
 d = [datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1e3) for x in ts]                          
 t = md.date2num(d)                                                       

 xfmt = md.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')                                      
 loc = md.SecondLocator(interval=3)                                       
 ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)                                              
 ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)                                       
 ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)                                         
 ax.scatter(t, f, s=p)
```

Results in:

[image: caption]

Simply setting the xlim to the min/max of my data does not work.

```
plt.xlim(d[0],d[-1])
```

Results in:

```
RuntimeError: RRuleLocator estimated to generate 42388816 ticks from 2013-11- 
09 00:44:48.845835+00:00 to 2017-11-19 20:45:37.472159+00:00: exceeds 
Locator.MAXTICKS * 2 (2000)
```

Why on earth is it trying to generate ticks between 2013 and 2017 ? The data I have coming in and want to plot is captured in real time and the timestamps are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, strangely enough, added a print statement, saved, and everything suddenly worked. Some strange caching issue going on I guess.  xlim seems to be respected properly now. Sigh..